# Jumping to hypertarget in a longtable lands too low in the row

Tags: longtable

I need your help in the following. I have hypertargets in the rows of a `longtable`, but when I jump to those by clicking on the corresponding hyperlink, I end up at the BOTTOM of the row, as opposed to the top.

Actually, I have also had this issue with regular `tabular` before, but to my greatest surprise and joy I discovered that if the hypertarget is in a manually-sized `m{<size>}` column as opposed to an `l` column, the jump happens correctly to the top of the table row. However, with `longtable`s not even this trick solves the problem. Consider the example below. When jumping into the dummy phrases table, the top of the targeted row is cut off. The corny phrases table is working well, but change `m{1cm}` to `l` in the tabular definition, it will show the same problem with the positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ m{1cm} l }
\caption{Dummy Phrase Repo} \\
\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Text} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\hypertarget{dummy1}{}1 & Lorem ipsum \\
\hypertarget{dummy2}{}2 & Quick brown fox \\
\hypertarget{dummy3}{}3 & Foo bar baz \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Corny Phrase Repo}
\begin{tabular}{ m{1cm} l }
\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Text} \\
\midrule
\hypertarget{corny1}{}1 & Attaboy! \\
\hypertarget{corny2}{}2 & Ahoy matey! \\
\hypertarget{corny3}{}3 & Thanks a lot, Lancelot! \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage

Angelina used dummy phrase \hyperlink{dummy2}{\#2} in her slides, evoking corny phrase \hyperlink{corny1}{\#1} from Billybob.

\end{document}
```

So my questions are:

1. What is it exactly that makes a difference between the `m` and `l` columns in a tabular?
2. Why doesn't the same thing make a difference in a `longtable`?
3. How to make this hypertarget jump work correctly in a `longtable` as well?

I see that answers to similar questions have some serious TeX-level wizardry. But isn't there a simpler solution (like in case of tabular there was)? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could make it easier to answer your question by showing some compilable examples.

Comment: the handling of the content of the table rows in `longtable` and `tabular` is identical, it uses the same code. longtable is essentially just a sequence of slightly modified tabular environments strung together. `m` is a vertically centered `\parbox` `l` is a left aligned `\mbox`

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm gonna add the examples to my question.

Comment: Worst case you can use \raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{dummy2}{\strut}} (for example).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks a lot, John; it worked! (It jumps to a position slightly higher than in case of `tabular`, but it's perfect this way as well.) However, I'm still trying to understand the **root cause** of the artifact I'm seeing. I read up a little bit on the different boxes & tables (and now I know who David really is! :-) ), but it's not obvious why `longtable` behaves differently from `tabular`. What is the landing position for a `hypertarget` in theory, and why does it change location for a `longtable`?

Answer (score 3):

The link target is set on the base line and should be moved between to just *before* the current row. In general, `\vadjust pre{...}` helps to put stuff into the vertical list *before* the current line. The keyword `pre` is an addition invented by pdfTeX and is also available for XeTeX and LuaTeX:

```
\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{dummy2}{}}
```

The vertical list in the first column is `m`, which is based on the `p` column type. This means, the cell contains a `\parbox` with material in vertical mode. Thus `\vadjust pre` goes into this list and it depends on the height of this and the other cells, if this is on top of the full table row.
With column types `l` and `r`, the target goes before the table cell out of alignment to the left of the current text line, not left to the table.

Putting stuff out of alignment can also be done with `\noalign`, which is restricted to the place, when the previous table row is finished and the new row is about to start:

```
... previous table row\\
\noalign{\hypertarget{dummy2}{}} First cell & ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I ended up going with John Kormylo's suggestion of `\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{dummy2‌​}{\strut}}`. It's working well, although it won't take you to the very top of the row, if the row contains multiple lines. (I'm still looking for the full explanation of why hypertarget is not behaving correctly in a longtable).